# Nutch - Job Failed - ERROR mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: apache, nutch

I am trying to follow simple the steps on the [Nutch tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A3._Crawl_your_first_website). This is my first time using Nutch.

All goes good till I execute the following command:

```
bin/nutch crawl bin/urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5 -threads 1
```

which gives me the following error

```
    log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/logs/hadoop.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:216)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:257)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:689)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:647)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:544)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:440)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:476)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.<clinit>(Crawl.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [DRFA].
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: crawl
rootUrlDir = bin/urls
threads = 1
depth = 3
solrUrl=null
topN = 5
Injector: starting at 2013-04-02 19:08:03
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: bin/urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:296)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

My bin directory has:

1. nutch
2. crawl
3. urls/seeds.txt

Not sure where the problem is.

`hadoop.log` has following error:

```
2013-04-03 17:33:18,370 ERROR mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Mkdirs failed to create file:/usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/crawl/crawldb/1971189408/_temporary

2013-04-03 17:33:21,394 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0002

java.io.IOException: The temporary job-output directory file:/usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/crawl/crawldb/1971189408/_temporary doesn't exist!
```

Comment: Does your user have permissions to create that folder/file?

Comment: Thanks nimeshjm! I run the command with 'sudo -E'.. the FileNotFoundException is gone, but "Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!" remains

Comment: the issue was with my crawl result directory.

Comment: @change. I have similar problem like you. Could you tell me how do you solve  result directory issue? I have run the command with sudo like sudo bin/nutch crawl bin/urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5 -threads 1. but i got java_home not defined error

Comment: the issue was with '-dir crawl'. You need to mention the correct directory path/name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `-dir crawl`.

You need to mention the correct directory `path/name`.

Comment: where does it expect to be pointing to? I'm running into similar issues.

Comment: You might need to add a directory at nutch/crawl for example, then point it there with the  bin/nutch crawl bin/urls -dir nutch/crawl -depth 3 -topN 5 -threads 1